# Testing Angular routes when using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I've written tests for an AngularJS application's routes before. For instance, here's part of one I wrote:

```
describe('Routes', function () {

    it('should map default route to home controller', function () {
        module('myapp');
        inject(function ($route) {
            expect($route.routes['/'].controller).toBe('HomeCtrl');
            expect($route.routes['/'].templateUrl).toEqual('/static/templates/home.html');
        });
    }); 
});
```

However, I'm currently working on an Ionic app, and it uses the `ui-router` from `angular-ui`, rather than Angular's default routes, so it uses `$state` rather than `$route`.

My question is, is there a similar way I can test using `$state`? I couldn't find anything likely-sounding in the documentation

Comment: Examine thi4s object in debugger `$state.$current.self` It has properties `controller`, `template`, `name`, `url` if they defined for this state

Comment: Hmm, I can get at `$state` in the debugger, but calling `$state.go()` in the test doesn't seem to do anything. I figure I may be missing something.

Comment: in tests you need to call a digest cycle manually to make things happen. At `$scope.` or `$rootScope.` call `$apply()` or `$digest();`